# Pausing/muting background music in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, text-to-speech, avaudiosession

I've got an app that uses text-to-speech to occasionally give verbal cues to the user. Currently I've set it up so the TTS mixes over any music that's playing in another app. Is there any way I could temporarily pause/mute music that's playing in another app while a verbal cue plays?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **MPMusicPlayerController** class and it's static method **iPodMusicPlayer** to get instance of the system (Music app) **MPMusicPlayerController** object. Then you can **pause**, **play** or anything else. The main condition is the other app is using **iPodMusicPlayer** object, the native music application player.

So you can control player only of some applications. Correct me, if I am wrong.

Here is the documentation: [MPMusicPlayerController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221)

Hope it helps